# MySQL auto-increment field by multiplication

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible without using triggers (if not then a working trigger would still be useful) to auto-increment a field by multiplying it?

E.g. I want the value of the fields to increase like so if I set it to multiply by 2:

```
1 - 2 - 4 - 8 - 16 - 32 - 64 - 128 - 256 - 512 - 1024 - 2048
```

Incase you were wondering this is to easier facilitate bitwise operations

Comment: Why do you need this in the database? Can't you just use the "normal" incrementing primary key as the exponent on a power-of-2 when you run the query or in application code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you set up a table, create an auto-increment field, but don't set it as the primary key.  Create a blank field for the primary key.  Now, whenever you run a query, just set the primary key to the value of the `2^(auto-increment field value)`.

Edit:  `field1` is primary key, `field2` is auto-increment, `field3` is data.

```
INSERT INTO table (field3) VALUES ("data");
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE table SET field1 = POW(LAST_INSERT_ID(),2);
```

Comment: This would not work, this would result in (2 - 4 - 6 - 8 - 10). I realise I can get the `max(ID)` and times that by 2 but don't want to add the extra queries if unnecessary and would rather MySQL handled it. This is also messy in the database, with unnecessary columns.

Comment: I said `^`, which means power.  so 2^1 = 2.  2^2 = 4; 2^3 = 8

Comment: my bad, but still not what I'm looking for really.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bit late, I just solved this using a `TRIGGER`: [Increment Table ID Field with Bitwise Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12412043/1431239)

Hopefully this helps those who stumble upon this question.