# Increment Table ID Field with Bitwise Counting

Tags: mysql, triggers, bit-manipulation

I am working on a project where I need my ID column to be a power of 2 (`1,2,4,8,16..`). I know that we cannot offset the `auto_increment` but for simple addition/subtraction in `my.cnf`.

Example:

```
id
----
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
etc
```

One of the ideas I had was to use the auto increment functionality as the base, and then create a trigger to apply the power of 2 and update the new ID, but unfortunately, it is not working:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER testbitcompatid BEFORE INSERT ON Table
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.id = pow(NEW.id, 2)
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Because the `BEFORE INSERT` has not yet generated the `AUTO_INCREMENT` `id`, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` will always return `0`, essentially causing no change on the columns.

I also tried `AFTER INSERT`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER testbitcompatid AFTER INSERT ON Table
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET Table.id = pow(NEW.id, 2) WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But this failed because you cannot change values of the table which the trigger is applied to during an `AFTER INSERT`.

Scratching my head, but I am sure someone else has a great way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Did you mean "*power of 2*" when you said "*multiple of 2*" in the first sentence?

Comment: It's unclear what values you want. You say you want the ids to be multiples of 2 (2,4,6,8, etc), which you can do using auto_increment_increment=2 and auto_increment_offset=2. The title of the question implies you want to use powers of 2 (2,4,8,16, etc). But then in your example, you are just raising everything to the second power (1,4,9,16). So which is it?

Comment: Correct, updated question to include, 1,2,4,8,16...

Comment: I do hope that you realize that the maximum size of a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` is 64 bits, and given this you'll be able to fit, say, 63 rows in that table at most.

Comment: @Charles.. yes that is something we thought of. for this project we expect no more than 20 rows at a given time which is far below the limitation. Thanks for mentioning though

Comment: Out of interest, why the requirement to store the calculated value of the power in your database and not just the exponent?  One can simply perform log/power calculations on data insertion/retrieval as required.

Comment: It's a dynamic table which holds constant like data. It uses bitwise operators for AND/OR/XOR etc for comparisons in other tables. It essentially removed the need to have a mapping/relationship table which reduces the footprint. The same values are then exported into both a PHP and C application and used as flags in specific functions. AND'ing and OR'ing these values is much cleaner and simpler in the end application than having to do extra math in the app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To work around all the issues above, I was able to construct the following which works great!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER testbitcompatid BEFORE INSERT ON Table
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET @LAST_ROW = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table);
        SET NEW.id = CASE WHEN @LAST_ROW IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @LAST_ROW * 2 END;

    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pretty much, we take the highest `id`, grab the `log(2)` of it which gives us the corresponding `AUTO_INCREMENT` `id`. We then add `1`, and power that up to `2`.

I hope this helps prevent some headache down the road for others.

Comment: Why aren't you just multiplying the value by 2?

Comment: That trigger does not satisfy your requirement. I think you meant to do this: `SET NEW.id = pow(2,log2((SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table)) + 1);`

Comment: @IkeWalker, it was working, but take a look at the updated answer. This accounts for the first 2 rows to be entered into the table to make sure it's not 0, and uses a var to prevent two calls for `Table.id`