# mysql bitmask ID field

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, bitmask

How can I create table that automatically increments a second column (BitField) on the ID autoincrement?

```
ID: 0 ->  BitField: 2^0 = 1
ID: 1 ->  BitField: 2^1 = 2
ID: 2 ->  BitField: 2^2 = 4
ID: 3 ->  BitField: 2^3 = 8
ID: 4 ->  BitField: 2^4 = 16
ID: 5 ->  BitField: 2^5 = 32
ID: 6 ->  BitField: 2^6 = 64
//etc
```

This for a user table field that is a bitmask  (think along the lines of "permissions").  So a side question would be: Do you think having a one-to-many for the options and many-to-many table for granting to each user is a better implementation (not even sure how to then format all that info into one row so usin a bitmask)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412043/increment-table-id-field-with-bitwise-counting

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[BitField] AS (power((2),[id]))
                        ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

-- Testing
INSERT INTO Test(Id) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO Test(Id) VALUES(6)
INSERT INTO Test(Id) VALUES(8)

SELECT * FROM Test


Id  BitField
2   4
6   64
8   256
```

Comment: That's a mighty exotic `MySQL` version you've got there.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't see MySql in the title.